# Changing absolute paths in my code (mac) to relative paths for my pc

Tags: java, path, filesystems, transformation

I have a netbeans project setup with the following absolute paths pointing to files on my harddrive.

```
/Users/Name/NetBeansProjects/DissertationUpnpDevices/src/my/upnpdevices/MSXbox360Device.java
/Users/Name/NetBeansProjects/DissertationUpnpDevices/src/my/upnpdevices/resources/description/MS_Xbox360description.xml
```

I will be moving my project over to a pc and I've been trying to convert the above paths into relative paths. But it's not working out for me. So far I have tried:

```
private final static String DESCRIPTION_FILE_NAME = "resources\description\MS_Xbox360\description.xml";
private final static String DESCRIPTION_FILE_NAME = "resources\/description\/MS_Xbox360\/description.xml";
```

But the above 2 attempts don't work. They give me an 'illegal escape character' error. I have also tried the following below

```
private final static String DESCRIPTION_FILE_NAME = "resources/description/MS_Xbox360/description.xml";
private final static String DESCRIPTION_FILE_NAME = "resources//description//MS_Xbox360//description.xml";
private final static String DESCRIPTION_FILE_NAME = "resources\\description\\MS_Xbox360\\description.xml";
private final static String DESCRIPTION_FILE_NAME = "./resources/description/MS_Xbox360/description.xml";
private final static String DESCRIPTION_FILE_NAME = ".//resources//description//MS_Xbox360//description.xml";
private final static String DESCRIPTION_FILE_NAME = ".\\resources\\description\\MS_Xbox360\\description.xml";
```

These all give me "`java.io.FileNotFoundException`". Any other suggestions as to how I can convert the absolute mac URI to a relative URI for my pc? The files on the pc are setup in the corresponding directories.

Comment: Relative to the netbeans project. The description.xml file resides in my netbeans project under a directory called 'resources'

Comment: Have you tried an absolute path? C:\etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the paths you have above should work fine for you (specific'./resources/description/MS_Xbox360/description.xml').  I just got done with a project and the Mac version didn't like relative paths with '\\' so I changed them to '/' and everything works fine now.  Also, the `java.io.FileNotFoundException` should print out what file it's looking for.  Inspect the error closely and make sure the file actual does or doesn't exist.

Comment: The file was missing... I can't believe it! I had moved the project over from a mac to the pc. Thanks for the help